# broken linux-generic or linux-headers-generic dependencies on 23.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:2 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease   
Hit:3 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease 
Hit:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                      
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease [109 kB]             
Hit:6 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                    
Fetched 109 kB in 0s (280 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
linux-generic/lunar-updates 6.2.0.24.24 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.2.0.23.23]
linux-headers-generic/lunar-updates 6.2.0.24.24 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.2.0.23.23]
linux-image-generic/lunar-updates 6.2.0.24.24 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.2.0.23.23]
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
$ sudo apt install linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-6.2.0-24-generic but it is not installable
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-6.2.0-24-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-24-generic but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:    23.04
Codename:   lunar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed now, indeed must have been 'not yet published packages'.

Answer (score 2):

I think canonical just forgot to publish the required packages it should fix itself after a few hours.
You're not the only one with the problem :D

The latest published version is 6.2.0-23
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-headers-6.2.0-&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all